# In App Purchase - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to add In-App Purchase to my app. My app is already on the App Store so I added my IAP's in iTunes Connect and I'm using the [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) from Github to do a purchase.

When I test my IAP in the sandbox they work fine but when I submit the app the testers tell me that they can't perform a purchase. What can cause this?

Comment: your guess is actually *better* than ours, because you have the code. Please post it!

Comment: I'm using SwiftyStoreKit from github, the same code as in their description.

Comment: Well, if it literally is **the same** code it will never work for your app.

Comment: Please give the exact error, an NSError or .Error(error: .PaymentNotAllowed) ?. The second error occurs when SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() return false

Comment: You should add more information on your issue; otherwise no one can answer it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps you have to take into account:

1: If the IAP's don't show in the app, make sure that you use the same bundle identifier for your AdHoc distribution as te one you created the IAP's for.

2: what Eugene said: for sandbox, only sandbox testers can purchase tests. Create sandbox testers and make sure your testers log out first in their own App Store account, before trying to make a purchase with the sandbox user

3: also make sure testers NEVER use the sandbox accounts to make actual purchases; this will convert the sandbox account to a live account.

Hope this was of any help :-)

IAP's aren't that hard, you just have to make sure you don't mess anything up.

Answer (score 0):

Only Sandbox Testers can make test purchases. It's NOT the users who are listed in Internal and External testers lists. Check iTunes Connect => Users and Roles => Sandbox Testers.